# MySQL: Conditional INSERT ... SELECT for multiple rows with constant values

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I know how to insert multiple rows with constant values in a single query:

```
INSERT INTO table
VALUES
  (1, 'a', 'x'),
  (2, 'b', 'y'),
  (3, 'c', 'z');
```

But how do I do this conditionally? I want to make sure only non-existing* rows get inserted. Is it even possible to do it in a single query?

**A row exists when all its columns are identical to the one we are inserting*

Answer (score 2):

Use `INSERT IGNORE INTO` instead of `INSERT INTO`. The former will only insert rows, if no unique key constraints are violated.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table
VALUES
  (1, 'a', 'x'),
  (2, 'b', 'y'),
  (3, 'c', 'z');
```

Comment: But IGNORE will only check for existing **keys**. Fortunately this works for my setup. But what if I wanted it to check **everything** (including non-key columns)?